# Cache the Github API response for search/repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, pagination, github-api

I want to write a web app in rails to search the Github repositories. Since there are limits on querying the Github API, I think it's a good idea to cache the response. 
This endpoint `search/repositories?q=search_term` returns the results in a paginated format. So, I am not sure how to do caching in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to concatenate pagination in a cache, but all of them require making new requests to each page in the pagination.

So, let user intuition reign. If a user needs a next page, give them the option to click "next page" and have that follow the link header provided by Github. How would that look in your cache? Since they provide a convenient `page=2` param at the end of the URL, why don't you just use the URLs the user is requesting as the key and the value is the response.

```
url = "api.github.com/search/resource?q=name:cool+name"
if(get(url)) return get(url)

response = get(url)
set(url, response)
return response
```

If a user clicks "next page" you should be making this request:

```
url = "api.github.com/search/resource?q=name:cool+name&page=2"
if(get(url)) return get(url)

response = get(url)
set(url, response)
return response
```

But see how the process doesn't change? If it's in the cache, send it. If it's not, don't.

Why don't we want to cache all pages recursively? Because humans know best. Computers would happily cache 1,000,000 responses for every search. But what if 99.99% of people are just looking for the first page's response? Why waste all that space? So, with pagination, it's always easiest to let people choose if they need more data. Don't try to pre-cache data that might never be used.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree with your idea and actually before asking on Stackoverflow I was imagining the same way to go.
I just have one confusion, how we achieve caching for each pages? Do I need to do something like this
`Rails.cache.fetch("#{repo_name}_#{count}", expires_in: 1.hour) do
  HTTParty.get("api.github.com/search/resource", { query: {page: count}, q: repo_name )
end`

So my cache key will be unique by `repo_name` and `page no.`

Comment: I would write to the cache with the actual URL. You can append queries to the URL like "api.github.com/search/resource?q=name:cool+thing&page=2". It would end up looking like this: 

`Rails.cache.write(url, response)` for any request. The queries would be in the actual URL. So each URL would be the unique key.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks